# How to check which string in an array is the longest one and each letter of the string is same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an Interview question today that "Please find the longest and same-letter string in an array". For example: ["a", "b", "aaaaa", "bbbca"]. The following steps is what I came out with in the interview.

**1. sort the array**

`let newArr = arr.sort((a, b)=> b.length - a.length)`

**2. filter not-match string which length is less than the first string**

`let matchString = newArr.filter(item=> item.length >= newArr[0].length)`

**3. Find the same-letter string**

define a function to check each letter in the string

Is there any more efficient way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to check whether the string consists of repeating characters, and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to the longest string with repeating characters:

```js
const s = ["a", "b", "aaaaa", "bbbca"];

const r = s.reduce(
  (a, v) => v.length > a.length && v.match(/^(.)\1*$/) ? v : a,
  ''
);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and check if the length is greater than the longest string and if all character are the same.

```js
function longestSameLetterString(array) {
    let longest = '';
    
    outer: for (const string of array) {
        if (string.length <= longest.length) continue;
        for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
            if (string[0] !== string[i]) continue outer;
        }
        longest = string;
    }
    
    return longest;
}

console.log(longestSameLetterString(["a", "b", "aaaaa", "bbbca"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to filter the elements in the array where the characters in the string are all same.
Using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the elements based on length.

```js
function longestSameLetterString(array) {
  return array
    .filter((item) => item[0].repeat(item.length) === item)
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
}

console.log(longestSameLetterString(["a", "b", "aaaaa", "bbbca"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string has all the same characters, we can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check each one against the first.  To do this, we [destructure] the argument into a first character and the remaining ones.  (This sort of destructuring makes an array of characters from a string.)  Then with `every` we simply test for a match.  This short-circuits if any value does not match, so it's reasonably efficient. This is done in the function `allSame`.

Then to find the longest one we use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), starting with the empty string, and at each step checking first that the length is longer than our longest so far and calling `allSame` if it is.  If both are true we continue with this string as the new longest value.  Otherwise we keep our current champion.  This will be more efficient than a `sort`, which at best is `O (n log n)`.  This is `O (n)`.

While we could inline the `allSame` function into `longestSame`, and probably squeeze out a bit more performance, I find this code much more readable as is.

```js
const allSame = ([c, ...cs]) => 
  cs .every (s => s == c)

const longestSame = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => x .length > a .length && allSame (x) ? x : a, '')

console .log (
  longestSame (["a", "b", "aaaaa", "bbbca"])
)
```